# How do I display a certain element of an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a credit card program that tells you what card should be paid off first. All the cards are read in from the user.
My issue seems to be that I cannot find a way to display the card with the highest interest rate.

I have set up a method called findHighestRate and it's job (as you guessed) is to look through the array and find the highest interest rate that was input from the user. Now I believe that portion of the code is correct, however I have tried countless times to display just the highest one through my display method (displays all the user input in a chart) but have come up short every time.

```
public static void header ()
{
    System.out.printf("%9s %22s %24s %29s" , "Card" , "Rate of Interest" , "Current Amount Owed", "Amount owed in One Year");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("============================");
    System.out.print("=================================================================");
    System.out.print("=====");
}

public static void display (String card [], double rOI [], double current [], double owed1yr [], int i)
{

    System.out.printf("\n%11s %14.2f %25.2f %25.2f" , card[i], rOI[i], current[i], owed1yr[i]);
}

public static String getString (String s)
{
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner (System.in);
    //prompt

    System.out.print(s+": ");
    return keyIn.nextLine().trim();
}

public static int findHighestRate(double interestRate [], int index )
{
    double max = 0;
    index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < interestRate.length; i++)
        if (interestRate[i] > max){
            max = interestRate[i];
            index = i;
    }
    return index;
}

public static double getDouble( String s)

{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner (System.in);
    // Prompt the user for the string needed
    System.out.print(s+": ");
    return stdIn.nextDouble();

}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    //bringing arrays to life.
    String [] c = new String [4];   
    double [] rateOfInterest = new double [4];
    double [] currentAmountOwed = new double [4];
    double [] yr1Owed = new double [4];

    int index =0;
    intro();
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the card, interest rate, and amount owed");
    for (int i = 0; i <c.length; i++){
        System.out.println();

        c[i] = getString ("Card");
        rateOfInterest [i] = getDouble("Rate of interest");
        currentAmountOwed [i] = getDouble ("Amount Owed");

    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int i =0 ; i < c.length; i++){
        yr1Owed[i] = ((rateOfInterest[i] * currentAmountOwed[i]   / 100) + currentAmountOwed[i]);
    }

    header();

    for ( int i = 0; i <c.length; i++)
    {
        display(c, rateOfInterest, currentAmountOwed,yr1Owed, i  );

    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Seach for the highest rate of interest.. Pay this off first");
    System.out.println();
    header();

    for ( int i = 0; i <c.length; i++)
    {

        FIND HIGHEST RATE METHOD HERE

    }

    //highest rate part of code not included..... did not complete.
}
```

}

Comment: You have a `findHighestRate` method. Why aren't you invoking it? Why does it have an `index` parameter? Why are you modifying it right away?

Comment: Because I need to print out the highest rate, by invoking that nothing would be printed would it? As far as the index being passed as a parameter, thats the place holder of the array, right?

Comment: `findHighestRate` returns something. What is that value? What does it represent? How do you access an element of an array? If you can access it, can't you print it? What does _place holder of the array_ **mean**? If you're just going to modify it right away, what's the point of having it provided by a caller?

Comment: I would like it to return the index of where the highest value is. In the main I am just not sure how to get that index displayed because if I were to say "findHighestRate(rateOfInterest)" nothing is printed. I also tried using the display method.  I am not sure why I had the index in the parameter list. As you can see as well, rather confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method

```
// I've removed the index parameter as it makes no sense
public static int findHighestRate(double interestRate [])
```

has a return type, `int`. As such, you have to make the method return a value. If it returns a value, you can assign the value to a variable or use it as an argument to another method.

For example

```
int index = findHighestRate(someDoubleArray);
```

You can then use that variable's value to access an element in the array

```
double highestRate = someDoubleArray[index];
```

You can then print out that value

```
System.out.println(highestRate);
```

Comment: @TylerB You're welcome. It's unclear what you're asking there, but I will suggest that you stop what you're doing which seems like a lot all at once. Review how arrays work. Review how methods work and how they are invoked. The official Java tutorials are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/). Go through them carefully.